# Execute a string as a command in python

Tags: python, django, path

I am developing my stuff in python. In this process I encountered a situation where I have a string called "import django". And I want to validate this string. Which means, I want to check whether the module mentioned('django' in this case) is in the python-path. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you writing and interpreter for Python?  Why would you ever need to validate Python code?

Comment: This sounds very dangerous. You might want to explain why you need to do that and see if someone comes up with a different way to accomplish it. Also, I assume the string isn't "called" "import django", but that that's what its contents is, right?

Comment: @akaihola: let me tell you the use case. I am writing an application level import checker, which will be scanning all the python files for import statements and will try to validate each one, by interpering them individually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong -- i didn't think to test my code. This actually works, though: look at the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module.

To just check for the module's importability in the current sys.path:

```
try:
    imp.find_module('django', sys.path)
except ImportError:
    print "Boo! no django for you!"
```

Comment: Nosklo & Yoni Samlan, I am having the same statements like these: "from mysite.models import Blog" etc.. So I wanted to intrepet this string to validate the exact import scenario. So I think I can't use Yoni's approach. Can I?

Answer (score 1):

I doub't that it's safe, but it's the most naïve solution:

```
try:
     exec('import django')
except ImportError:
    print('no django')
```

Comment: Avoid using exec when you can.

Answer (score 1):

If a module's name is available as string you can import it using the built-in `__import__` function.

```
module = __import__("module name", {}, {}, [], -1)
```

For example,

```
os = __import__("os", {}, {}, [], -1)
```

Comment: To check whether the module is there, you'd need to wrap this in try...except ImportError.